# remove values in range using input box

Tags: excel, vba

hey guys I have this code below. I want to remove the range of values selected by users. so if the user selects 115,116,117 delete those three rows? should I be using some type of loop? Now it's just deleting the first Value. thank you!

```
Dim sIDNumber, sResponse As String

sIDNumber = Application.InputBox("Enter ID's to delete from workbook: ", "Enter ID's", , 200, 200)

If sIDNumber = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If

sResponse = MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to remove " & sIDNumber & " from the entire workbook?", vbYesNo, "Delete: " & sIDNumber & "?")

If sResponse = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
End If
Dim myCell, myRange As Range
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Dim bIDFound As Boolean

For Each mySheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If TargetSheetName(mySheet.Name) = True Then
        For Each myCell In mySheet.Range("C1:CA20000")
            If CStr(myCell.Value) = sIDNumber Then
                myCell.EntireRow.Delete
                bIDFound = True
            End If
        Next myCell
    End If
Next mySheet

If bIDFound = True Then
    MsgBox "ID " & sIDNumber & " was removed!"
Else
    MsgBox "ID " & sIDNumber & " was NOT found!"
End If

End Sub

''this is just a case to remove from all sheets
Function TargetSheetName(sSheetName As String) As Boolean

Select Case sSheetName
    Case "Sheet 1"
        TargetSheetName = True
    Case "Sheet 2"
        TargetSheetName = True
    Case "Sheet 3"
        TargetSheetName = True
    Case "Sheet 4"
        TargetSheetName = True
    Case "Sheet 5"
        TargetSheetName = True
End Select

End Function
```

Comment: you need a way for the user to enter multiple ids and then a loop to iterate them. So, for example a comma separate string that gets loaded into an array with the split function.

Comment: Don't forget to remove them in reverse order. From largest to smallest row number. And I believe you can use find to find the matching ID number instead of looping through each cell of the sheet like that.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman yes I tired an array that dint work. but I did not try to split them! that may work.!

Comment: @andreas ill try it find but how will it go through all ids? without looping.

Comment: Without looping.. not sure that is possible. Perhaps if you use a filter. I think the criteria can accept array as input. That way you filter out what you want to delete and then delete the visible rows.